# How to open exec path going up a directory in node.js?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to open an exe in node

```
exec('../logic_parser/logic_parser/bin/Debug/logic_parser.exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

but it complains that `..` is not a command. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

Comment: How do I use that? Show code pls

Comment: `exec('logic_parser', {cwd: '../logic_parser/logic_parser/bin/Debug/'}, (error, stdout, stderr) ...`?

Comment: that worked, thanks